# How to receive data with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am working on a front and back end for a website. I try to send data to my back end but I can't seem to parse it in any way. I am using node.js and express to build the backend. I do not understand how I could access my sent data from my website.

This is how I send my data to my server. I checked and when sending the data it is correctly sent as valid json.

```
function submitForm(){
  name = document.getElementById('customer_name1').value;
  parent_name = document.getElementById('parent_name').value;
  smyID = document.getElementById('symID');
  customer_id = uuidv4();
  loc1 = document.getElementById('loc1').value;
  location_id = uuidv4();
  r_name = document.getElementById('room_name');
  r_symID = document.getElementById('rsym_id');
  room_id = uuidv4();
  d_e164 = document.getElementById('e164').value;
  username = document.getElementById('u_name').value;
  user_password = document.getElementById('u_pass');
  ip_adr = document.getElementById('ip_adr').value;
  device_id = uuidv4();
  var customer = {
    customer_name: [name, customer_id, parent_name, symID],
    locations: [loc1, location_id, customer_id],
    rooms: [r_name, room_id, location_id, r_symID],
    devices: [room_id, d_e164, username, user_password, ip_adr, device_id]
  };
  var data = JSON.stringify(customer);
  var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
      xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.open("post", 'http://localhost:3000/users', true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/application/json;charset=UTF-8');
  xhttp.send(data);
```

I previously had a version where I could get the data I wanted, but I want to make one api call instead of 5 different ones to do this. Here is what worked before.

```
function createUser(req, res, next) {
  let user_id = uuidv4();
  let new_customer = new PQ('insert into customer(customer_name, ID, parent, symID) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)');
  new_customer.values = [req.body.customer_name, user_id, req.body.parent, req.body.symID];
  db.none(new_customer)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({
        id: user_id
      })
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
  });
}
```

When I try to post anything to the serve I just get a 500 error. No other description of any sort.

update: when I try to just do a simple function with a console.log in it I get no data sent when I use the send method!

Comment: are you using express.js?

Comment: yes I am using express

Answer (score -1):

Did you try console.log() these values

> req.body.customer_name, user_id, req.body.parent, req.body.symID

on the server? just to see if you can get those.

Maybe try parsing the body back to json using JSON.parse()

Comment: ok, then maybe try doing JSON.parse(req.body) and put that inside another variable AND use that variable when you're setting new customer values